# How do I stream response in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, express

I've been trying to get a express app to send the response as stream.

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var rs = Readable();


app.get('/report', function(req,res) {
    
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/csv');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Header to force download
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=Report.csv');

    
    rs.pipe(res);

    rs.push("USERID,NAME,FBID,ACCOUNT,SUBSCRIPTION,PRICE,STATE,TIMEPERIOD\n");

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        rs.push("23,John Doe,1234,500,SUBSCRIPITON,100,ACTIVE,30\n");
    }

    rs.push(null);
});
```

It does print in the console when I replace "rs.pipe(res)" by "rs.pipe(process.stdout)". But how to make it work in an express app?

```
Error: not implemented
    at Readable._read (_stream_readable.js:465:22)
    at Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:341:10)
    at Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:720:14)
    at Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:575:10)
    at line "rs.pipe(res);"
```

Comment: You need to subclass [`Readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_readable_stream), which needs to have a `_read` method. But why not just use `res.write(...)`?

Comment: how would i use res.write() here?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You don't need a readable stream instance, just use `res.write()`:

```
res.write("USERID,NAME,FBID,ACCOUNT,SUBSCRIPTION,PRICE,STATE,TIMEPERIOD\n");

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    res.write("23,John Doe,1234,500,SUBSCRIPITON,100,ACTIVE,30\n");
}

res.end();
```

This works because in Express, `res` is based on Node's own [`http.serverResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse), so it inherits all its methods (like [`write`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback)).

Comment: Will this still not be a problem if i add thousands of lines to the response?

Comment: No, because `res` is also a stream.

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying to do it with the readable stream all day.

Comment: this will not stream,buffers till res.end() is called

Comment: @chetandev your browser/client might buffer it, but Express or `http` doesn't. You can test this using a non-buffering TCP-client like `nc/netcat`. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/93fb9122a20e4acacc44161fbacca496).

Comment: I've found it is important, to initially send header first. Otherwise the client side won't receive streaming until `res.end()`.

Comment: @BartoszRosa how can i do that

Comment: @Anthony https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#responseflushheaders

Comment: @robertklep any way to prevent browser/client from buffering it? I'd like to use axios but fetch is also fine.

Comment: @ZulluBalti either implementation would need to support streaming responses (for fetch, [look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams); for axios, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71534322/http-stream-using-axios-node-js)).

Answer (score 17):

I was able to get this to work.

- Put this code in your Express router.
- Open a web browser
- Go to http://yourdomain/yourrouterpath/stream

...

```
router.get('/stream', function (req, res, next) {
  //when using text/plain it did not stream
  //without charset=utf-8, it only worked in Chrome, not Firefox
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
  res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');

  res.write("Thinking...");
  sendAndSleep(res, 1);
});


var sendAndSleep = function (response, counter) {
  if (counter > 10) {
    response.end();
  } else {
    response.write(" ;i=" + counter);
    counter++;
    setTimeout(function () {
      sendAndSleep(response, counter);
    }, 1000)
  };
};
```

Comment: Any ideas why this doesnt work with Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 ??

Comment: Wow thank you so much for this answer. I was setting the content type to text/plain and couldn't figure out for the life of me why it wasn't streaming. You can also just not set the header, start writing, & it will work.

Comment: MDN notes the use of 'Transfer-Encoding' is disallowed in HTTP/2 (except in one case, which is not this one): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding

Comment: it's probably still delivered streaming to the client, but without the charset specified, the browser probably waits to receive a bunch of data to guess what the charset is before rendering any of it

Answer (score 9):

I needed to stream a response in express in order to work with tar-stream. Here is how I did it in case it helps anyone.

The requests are for a single file from a tar file stored on the server.

```js
const fs = require("fs"),
   tar = require("tar-stream");

app.get("/fileFromTar/*", (req, res) => {
   const fileWanted = req.params[0],
      readStream = fs.createReadStream('myTarFile.tar'),
      extractor = tar.extract();

   extractor.on('entry', (header, stream, next) => {
      stream.on('end', next);

      if (header.name === fileWanted) {
         const { size } = header;
         res.set({
           "Content-Type": 'audio/flac', // or whichever one applies
           "Content-Length": size,
           "Content-Range": `bytes 0-${size}/${size}`
         });
         stream.pipe(res);
      }
      else stream.resume();
   });
   readStream.pipe(extractor);
});
```