# How to return 2 response for a single request in node.js

Tags: node.js

My node app is simple, for a request querying the total customers in mysql databases, i do a block call using await to wait for query to finish.
The problem is it can only handle ~75 requests per second, too low.

So i try to return 200 whenever i get the request, telling caller i get the request. 
Then return the query result when ready， mysql query could take a while.

But not working for me yet, this is the code:

router:

```
router.get('', controller.getCustomers）;
```

controller:

```
const getCusomers = (req, res) => {
    try {
        service.getCustomers(res);
        res.write('OK');
        //res.send(200); this will end the response before query ends
    } catch (err) {
        res.end(err);
    }
```

service:

```
const getCustomers = async (res) => {
    customers = await mysqlPool.query('select * from cusomerTable');
    res.send(customers);
}
```

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client.

How to fix this pls ?

Comment: It looks like you're writing "OK" to the response after you await grabbing the data from your service.. Basically, what is happening is: client sends request -> server gets it -> you query mysql -> you send query results -> you write "OK" .. things are not happening in the order you think they are. `service.getCustomers` contains a blocking call... that is why you get the error about headers..(specifically, res.write is causing error) I dont understand the need/want to notify the client you got the request. if youre sending the req using XHR it shoudnt block the browser from doing its thing..

Comment: With that being said, a 200 will close communication, I dont think it fits here, but you can look more into [206 Partial Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206).. Or use res.write(customers) versus res.send(customers) as this streams the response...All in all, I think you should just let the client wait for the response, without letting them know you got it... I don't understand the use case, so it's hard for me to see why you would want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Server-Sent Events**. You can send an event as soon as you get the request.
When the result is ready, you can send another event. Kindly find my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sudhakar3697/Express-SSE-Sample) useful for a SSE sample.

OR

You can just use res.write() to stream the response. Find this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38789462/12167785) useful.

Comment: Initially i was planning to use res.write() in controller, then res.json() in service as mysql query returns a json object. It didn't work. Since you said so, i replaced res.json() with res.write(JSON.stringify(queryResult); res.end(). It worked, doesn't make any sense, i thought res.json() is doing the similar thing.